# use of media in css attribute

Tags: css, media-queries

**CSS**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="screen and (max-width: 480px)"  href="example.css">
```

what is the use of `media="screen and (max-width: 480px)` in this css attribute. Is this related with `@media only screen (max-width: 480px)` in css body. **Please explain about this.** I can't really understand.

If yes,

**CSS**

```
   /* For mobile phones: */
[class*="col-"] {
    width: 100%;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    /* For tablets: */
    .col-m-1 {width:8.33%;}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    /* For desktop: */
    .col-1 {width:8.33%;}
}
```

I have three formate for mobile, desktop and tablet in my CSS body. In this type how will I put it. Do I need to put multiple media tag in my css attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, its related.

You can use `media queries` in few ways.

You can declare some stylles in CSS body as You writed:

```
@media only screen (max-width: 480px)
```

Or You can specife in html which .css file will be used in which situation:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="screen and (max-width: 480px)"  href="example.css">
```

So You can use media queries in multiple ways.
I suggesty You, when You have several lines of css code to put in media - use this inline form in css body. When You want to put some big amount of code -it's better to refactor this to different files. The code will be more clean and decent.